# Why can't I display data from Mongodb with Angular

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

and I am trying to display a collection called books in mongodb but for some reason I run into an `ng-repeat` dupes error. Also the data retrieved from my `$http.get` operation returns the HTML syntax of the entire page for some reason instead of accessing the data from the books collection. Thing is I created other programs prior to this where I had absolutely no problem with `ng-repeat` and they still work, the difference being the angular version is older. I am thinking that is the problem. If you have any insight on what I am doing wrong I would appreciate it. Thank you

Error:

> Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=book%20in%20library&p1=string%3A%3C&p2=%3C

Controller code:

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("bookCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
    var refresh=function(){
     $http.get('http://localhost:3000/storeHome').success(function(response){
     console.log("I got the data I requested");
     console.log(response); //returns HTML of the page instead of an object
     $scope.library = response;
     $scope.book="";
     });
   };
   refresh();
   });
```

Route code:

```
     var express = require('express');
     var router = express.Router();
     var Book =require('../../models/book');

     router.get('/', function(req, res) {
     res.render('bookStore/storeHome');
     });

     //get all books from the database
     router.get('/',function(req,res,next){
     Book.find(function(err, books) {
     if (err)
     res.send(err);
     console.log(books);
     res.json(books);
     });
     });
```

Book model:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
       title: String,
       author: String,
       publisher: String,
       year: Number
     });
     module.exports=mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema);
```

HTML

```
   <div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="bookCtrl">  
   <table class="table">
    <!--omitted code in between -->
   <tr ng-repeat="book in library"> <!-- I tried track by $index and it didn't work-->   
   <td>{{book.title}} </td>
  </tr>
  </div>
```

Comment: `track by $index` should work in your case

Comment: ok I think the issue lies within my route. The find function works correctly but I guess having to route.get() functions serves as some conflict i think? What I think i need to do is to figure out how to render the page and send the json object over too, but node.js complains about having res.render and res.json, if i could combine them it could work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the nodejs response is wrong. The res.json...try another options please.

EDIT: LIke this: res.status(200).send({myBooksList:list})

or this: res.send(200,{myBooksList:list})

Im still not sure :D, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Change your template's ng-repeat to :

```
<tr ng-repeat="book in library track by $index">
```

It doesn't handle duplicate data very well as it tries to find an identifier that is unique for every item. But since there's duplicates in the data angular is unable to do so... We can use the assigned repeat index to track the item by.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
Book.find(function(err, books) {
  if (err)
    res.send(err);
    res.end(JSON.stringify(books));
  }
}));
```